# sort an implemented link list

Tags: java

iam supposed to display a customer records from a txt file,and then re display them in ascending order.I have the first part but am failing to figure out the sorting.here is what i have under the method     public void add(Customer newNode, int dummy)

```
public void add(Customer newNode, int dummy)

    {
    if (head == null) // The first node
    {
    head = tail = this;
    head.setData(newNode); size=1;
    return;
    } //************need to figure this out
    CustomerList t = new CustomerList();
    head.setNext(temp);
       getHead().getNext();
       head = temp;

       //this is the part am trying to figure out

    ++size;
    } // add
// Append the new node to the end of list
public void  add(Customer newNode)
   {
   if (head == null) // The first node
      {
      head = tail = this;
      head.setData(newNode);
      size=1;
      return;
      }
   CustomerList temp = new CustomerList(newNode);
   tail.setNext(temp);
   getHead().getNext();
   tail = temp;
   ++size;
   } // add

// retrieve a specific node by index
// The index starts with 0
public Customer get(int which)
   {  
   if (which > size-1)
      return null;
   if (size < 0)
      return null;
   CustomerList temp = head;
   for (int k=0; k < size; ++k)
       {
       if (which == k)
          break;
       temp = temp.getNext();
       }
   return temp.getData();
   } // get
```

Comment: Are you allowed to used "standard java" stuff like collections and algorithms or are you expected to do it all yourself?

Answer (score 1):

use **Collections.sort(your List)** to get the List in a sorted order.

Then to display them get an iterator using **iterator()** method.

Then iterate the elements using **next()** method

Comment: I'm guessing he/she has to sort it without using `Collection.sort()`, considering it has the dreaded homework tag.

Comment: Am not allowed to use Collection.sort()I had tried that and was told to redo it.

Comment: @Angel918 can you say with which field you want to sort the records. I mean sort them using customer id or name or what?

Answer (score 1):

Start with implementing some methods that you will need:

```
public void remove(Customer customer);

public void insert(Customer customer, index);

public void swap(int index1, int index2);
```

With all algorithm you'll have to *take* an element from the list and *insert* it somewhere else in the list or simply swap to elements in the list.

Comment: great thanks let me try that.I think i already implemented public void insert()

Answer (score 0):

create comparator for Customer class or you can implements comparable interface for Customer class. Then use one of below sorting strategy:

1. If you have created comparator for your customer then use Collections.sort(your list, your comparator)
2. If you implemented comparable interface then use Collections.sort(your list)

Then for display purpose use iterator() method. And you can iterate next element of list through next() method.